# Can I import data into MySQL as a big string?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to import data like this:

`mysql> IMPORT DATA INTO db1.table_foo FROM RAW "col1 col2 col3\n10 2 6\n9 4 3\n8 8 2\n"`

Or like this:

`%> mysql --raw-option -u user db1.table_foo < cat "col1 col2 col3\n10 2 6\n9 4 3\n8 8 2\n"`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: input redirected into mysql MUST consist of actual sql statements. you can't just slam some randomish text into mysql (even if you do specify a table) and expect mysql to know what to do with it. how should it know if that's multiple columns, or a single columns separated by spaces, or some wonky combination of multiword and singleword fields?

Comment: Well the `LOAD DATA INFILE` function provides different methods for parsing a text file (csv, tsv), so i'm trying to use the same functionality 'in line' in a script.

Comment: Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [--execute or -e parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute) of mysql's command line utility to execute sql statements from a string. Mysql documentation on [command line options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/command-line-options.html) provides details on how to use this option:

> Option values that contain spaces must be quoted when given on the command line. For example, the --execute (or -e) option can be used with mysql to pass SQL statements to the server. When this option is used, mysql executes the statements in the option value and exits. The statements must be enclosed by quotation marks.
>
> [...]
>
> If you wish to use quoted values within a statement, you will either
>   need to escape the inner quotation marks, or use a different type of
>   quotation marks within the statement from those used to quote the
>   statement itself. The capabilities of your command processor dictate
>   your choices for whether you can use single or double quotation marks
>   and the syntax for escaping quote characters. For example, if your
>   command processor supports quoting with single or double quotation
>   marks, you can use double quotation marks around the statement, and
>   single quotation marks for any quoted values within the statement.
>
> Multiple SQL statements may be passed in the option value on the
>   command line, separated by semicolons

Still, the import must be executed as an sql statement. Cannot directly import using just data from a string.